# Generate a cURL request from a Postman

Tags: http, curl, postman, multipartform-data

I  tried generating a cURL request from Postman (using `code` option of postman).
As the request contains an input pdf file, there are certain header properties that are being added by postman.
Below is the curl that is generated (almost similar, changed some header for security reasons), response received `500, internal Server Error, "Current request is not a multipart request"`

```
  http://localhost:8080/test \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded,multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------895926775956600620357522' \
  -H 'Some-Key: abcd' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -F file=@/C:/path/to/my/file/abc.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the `multipart` request in Postman, you just need to do the following:

1. Don't specify a `Content-Type` in `Header`.
2. In `Body` tab of Postman you should select `form-data` and select `file type`

Read more [here](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/576).

Comment: I am able to get the response while I hit it from Postman, generating a cURL was the issue.